# Android debug Nexus 5x - files not visible on PC

Tags: android, usb

Q & A for problem I had that may help others:

Q. When connecting my Nexus 5x (Android 6.0.1) to PC (running ubuntu 14) using USB it gets detected by chrome://inspect but file explorer does not show any files (it shows Nexus 5x in file explorer but no directories or files). Works fine with other android device running Android 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Fixed problem by going to Android Settings / Developer Options / Select USB Configuration then chose PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol) rather than the default MTP.